# Using load() multiple times in R script

Tags: r

I'm running this R script in batch mode. The 4 file paths are passed in as named strings (inPath1...inPath3, outPath) by a shell script. Here is the shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash

R CMD BATCH --no-save --no-restore '--args inPath1="~/backtest/results/aapl-RESULTS.RData" 
                inPath2="~/backtest/results/adbe-RESULTS.RData" 
                inPath3="~/backtest/results/adi-RESULTS.RData" 
                outPath="~/backtest/profitBreakdown.csv' ~/Desktop/derp.R ~/Desktop/script.out
```

Here is the R script:

```
library(xts)

args <- commandArgs(trailingOnly=TRUE)

for(i in 1:3){
  eval(parse(text=args[i]))
  pathName <- paste("inPath", i, sep = "")
  load(pathName)  
}
```

I get the following error message in the output:

```
Error in readChar(con, 5L, useBytes = TRUE) : cannot open the connection
Calls: load -> readChar
In addition: Warning message:
In readChar(con, 5L, useBytes = TRUE) : cannot open compressed file 'inPath1', probable reason 'No such file or directory'
```

Why is this happening? The files and directories exist. I can double click on them and load them in with the mouse. Do I have to close the connection after using load() each time?

Comment: Do you think you could work on making this reproducible?  It's tough to debug code that we can't run.

Comment: Your use of `eval` looks dangerous: it is safer to parse the argument, e.g., with `strsplit` (or any other string manipulation function). You can try to add `stopifnot( file.exists(path) )` just before `load`, to make sure that the file indeed exists.

Comment: @GSee--Just edited it. Without making available the .RData files, I think this is as close as I can come to reproducibility.

Comment: I'm almost certain that the problem stems from your unnecessary use of `eval(parse(...))`. Don't pass the arguments as `inPath1 = ...`, instead just pass the paths themselves and extract the one you need when you need it.

Comment: On second thought, while the `eval(parse(...))` is bad, your immediate problem is that you are passing `"inPath1"` to `load`. That a raw character string, not a path to a file. Read the error message.

Comment: Why do you need to pass these as `commandArgs` at all? `list.files` or just include the paths as variables in the script itself?